# Use a global GeoJSON layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm using getJSON to draw points in Leaflet, this is the code:

```
function cargarpapes(movibles){
    $.getJSON("papeleras1.php", function(data) {           
        papesjson = L.geoJson(data, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.codigo);
            }
        });
        papesjson.addTo(map);          
    });
}
```

My question is simple, why I can not use the method `papesjson.addTo(map);` out of `$.getJSON()`, even when I have declared my variable papesjson as global at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$.getJSON()` is asynchronous. So only after your request to `papeleras1.php` get finished you can add it to the map.

You could add a listener to check when this happens. Like:

```
map.on('layeradd', function(layer, layername){
    //some action
});
```